# embedding luajit undefined reference

Tags: c++, windows, lua, makefile, luajit

I'm unsuccessfully trying to embed (statically) luajit into a c++ application. I have followed the steps from the luajit site to no avail, googled on the subject and got no relevant information and tried every thing I could think of.

It appears as if the problem I'm running in is that g++ doesn't quite link it properly, or perhaps luajit ins't building properly.

This is what I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main(void)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

And the error I'm getting is a `undefined reference` error almost as if I hadn't linked luajit at all.

```
main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `luaL_newstate()'
main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs(lua_State*)'
main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `lua_close(lua_State*)'
```

I'm trying to compile it with eclipse cdt (mingw) after setting the linking options as following:

```
Library Paths:        D:/includes/LuaJIT-2.0.1/src
Includes (GNU G++):   D:/includes/LuaJIT-2.0.1/src
Libraries:            luajit
```

And eclipse cdt appears to be trying to compile it as following:

```
g++ -ID:/includes/LuaJIT-2.0.1/src -O0 -g3 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -o "source\\main.o" "..\\source\\main.cpp" 
g++ -LD:/includes/LuaJIT-2.0.1/src -o test.exe "source\\main.o" -lluajit
```

I have downloaded [LuaJIT-2.0.1 zip](http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-2.0.1.zip) (latest version) from their [download page](http://luajit.org/download.html) and followed the [installation guide](http://luajit.org/install.html) as following:

- Unziped it.
- Fired up a cmd and cded to `LuaJIT-2.0.1/src/`
- Ran `make BUILDMODE=static` and got a nice `OK Successfully built LuaJIT` message

Other than that there ins't a lot of information on embedding luajit, not even in the [installation guide](http://luajit.org/install.html#embed).

However grepping the `src` folder for `luaL_newstate` returns a match in the `libluajit.a`.

```
grep -r "luaL_newstate" .

./host/genminilua.lua:  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
./host/minilua.c:static lua_State*luaL_newstate(void){
./host/minilua.c:lua_State*L=luaL_newstate();
./lauxlib.h:LUALIB_API lua_State *(luaL_newstate) (void);
Binary file ./libluajit.a matches
./lib_aux.c:LUALIB_API lua_State *luaL_newstate(void)
./lib_aux.c:LUALIB_API lua_State *luaL_newstate(void)
./lib_aux.c:  fputs("Must use luaL_newstate() for 64 bit target\n", stderr);
Binary file ./lib_aux.o matches
./lua.h:#define lua_open()      luaL_newstate()
Binary file ./luajit.exe matches
Binary file ./luajit.o matches
```

I'm using:

- mingw's `g++ (rev, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0 20130314 (experimental)`
- mingw's `GNU Make 3.82.90 Built for i686-pc-msys`
- Win8 64bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your `include` directives into `extern "C" { ... }`

Comment: Well, that was easy. It unfortunately doesn't point that out absolutely anywhere at all. It should at least be mentioned in the embedding part of the guide... Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `#include "lua.hpp"` in C++ code, *not* `lua.h`.

This is mentioned at the top of the [documentation for the C API](http://luajit.org/ext_c_api.html).